# Number of images being used for the annual product

Tags: metadata

I am using the v2.1 annual nighttime light (NTL) [product](https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/vnl/) for my analysis. My study areas are several megacities, which include:

Los Angles, Mexico City, Tehran, Paris, Cairo, Manila, Tokyo.

I would like to ask you if you could tell me where to find how many clear images have been used to create the annual products for the above megacities. I am using the `VNL_v21_npp_2018_global_vcmslcfg_c202205302300.average.dat.tif.gz` product for my analysis.

I have searched the website for any metadata but I couldn't find any relevant information.